# Suppose $f$ satisfies $m(\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)>y\}) \leq \frac{y}{(\ln y)^2}$ for $y \geq 2$. Show that $f$ is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f:[0,1] \to [0,\infty]$ is measurable and satisfies $$m(\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)>y\}) \leq \frac{1}{y\,(\ln y)^2}$$ for $y \geq 2$. Show that $f$ is integrable.

We want to show that $\int f\, dm<\infty$. Let $E=\{x \in [0,1]:f(x)>y\}$. Then, note that
$$\int f\, dm=\int_{E} f\, dm+\int_{E^c} f\, dm\, .$$

Now, I want to find an upper bound for the integrals. I am stuck as $$\int_{E^c} f\, dm \leq \int_{E^c} y\, dm \leq \, ?$$

Comment: This is not true. I think the right side should be $\frac  1 {y (\ln y)^{2}}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You are right. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a well known application of Fubini's Theorem we have $\int f(x)dx=\int_0^{\infty} m\{x: \in [0,1]: f(x) >y\}dy$. Hence $$\int f(x)dx$$ $$ \leq \int_0^{2} m\{x: \in [0,1]: f(x) >y\}dy$$ $$+\int_2^{\infty} m\{x\in [0,1]: f(x) >y\}dy$$ $$ \leq 2+ \int_2^{\infty}\frac  1 {y (\ln y)^{2}}dy$$ make the substitution $\ln y=z$ to show that the second term is finite.

The first step is justified as follows:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} m \{x: f(x) >y\}dy &= \int_0^{\infty} \int \chi _{\{x: f(x)>y\}} dm(x)dy \\
&=\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{f(x)} dy dm(x)\\
&=\int f(x)dm(x)\end{align}$$

Comment: I am not sure what application of Fubini's theorem you are talking about?

Comment: I have included a  proof.  @user330477

Comment: Thank you very much. Now everything makes sense.